# Access to top-level functions inside WebComponent

Tags: scope, dart, dart-webui

Is it possible to access top-level function inside Dart WebUI WebComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with Fancy Syntax. See the section on registering top-level variables: https://github.com/dart-lang/fancy-syntax#registering-top-level-variables